# Why does cast from IEnumerable<string> to List<string> fail?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, classcastexception

Why does the following not succeed in casting`IEnumerable<string>` to `List<string>`?

```
var l = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
l.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("a string", 1));
List<string> s = (List<string>)l.Select(x => x.Item1); // System.InvalidCastException
MessageBox.Show(s[0]);
```

Also, why is the exception not caught properly in Visual Studio? It appears in the debug window but doesn't stop execution of the program.

Comment: Because the IEnumerable it returns is *not* a List and casting  (which is different from implicit/explicit conversions) *cannot* change the type of an object: `l.Select(x => x.Item1).GetType().Name` <-- what's that? (Scala has a nifty Collection system where the type is usually preserved across such operations, but C# is not capable of such.)

Comment: @pst _casting cannot change the type of an object_ can you explain that part?

Comment: An object is what it is. i.e. A string is always a string. `object s = "foo"; (string)s` is okay because the type of the object is a `string` (that is, `s.GetType() == typeof(string)`); `object n = 1; (string)n` is *not* okay because the type (`int`) is not a `string` (or otherwise assignable) and the cast will fail. C# has implicit/explicit [*conversions*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39bb81c3.aspx) (which can look like casting :-/), but that is not casting in the same sense. With casting the input object and the output object are the *same*, but the "view" changes.

Comment: Consider this: `object a = "hi"; string s1 = (string)a;`, then `s1.ReferenceEquals(a)` is true. So it doesn't make sense to be able to say "turn this object that conforms to the IEnumerable interface into a List" when it is *not* a List (or a subtype of a List). This is what a ClassCastException means: can't change type.

Comment: @pst Ok, but (without knowing much about C#) "turn this object that conforms to the IEnumerable interface into a List" would seem like a perfectly well-defined operation to me. Are you saying that (in general) it requires a 'conversion' and hence a new object in memory, and that's why the 'view as' cast I'm using fails?

Comment: I am an `IPerson`. You are an `IPerson`. But it is not possible to `I = (Me)You`, because You are not Me.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx (tough read, but it touches on about everything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want the results as a `List<T>`, use:

```
List<string> s = l.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList()
```

Internally the `Select` method is *not* generating a `List` at all; the elements are returned on the fly as the `IEnumerable<T>` is iterated.

I would except the Exception to be caught. My guess would be that you have a catch (perhaps not one that you added) that is picking it up somewhere along the way.

Comment: I think Andrew is operating on the assumption that, while the static type is IEnumerable, the dynamic type is going to be List, because it's being selected out of a List. Can you clarify that this is not the case?

Comment: I was clarify as you wrote. :)

Comment: That assumption is bogus becuase when you would code that enumerator by hand you would not make it a list for efficientcy reasons. To BE A list, it has to be computed totally, which is a waste when not wanted as a list. An enumerator can just return rows on the fly during processing.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your approach is all wrong; you can convert the result of a Select into a list - just not like that - simply because it is an **IEnumerable** not a **List**. If you want a list then do

```
var string_list = l.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList();
```

If you absolutely, concretely, 100%, certainly **know** that you only have one element[1] then do:

```
var l = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
l.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("a string", 1));
MessageBox.Show( l.Select(x => x.Item1).First() );
```

If your list could contain more than one element then do

```
MessageBox.Show( String.Join(", ", l.Select(x => x.Item1)) );
```

If you want to work with LINQ effectively it's important to understand what's happening and to realize that what you are creating are somesort of result set - which is not the same as a primitive List and this is where IMO LINQ is incredibly powerful - you just need to understand it.

---

1 - In which case why are you working with a list....